# Plugin loaded but category in dropdown not loaded

Tags: shopware, psr-4

I am using Shopware 6. I would like to add a category in the dropdown of the Shopping Experiences and save my custom elements there. So I've made a plugin and added the corresponding code.

My composer.json

```
{
  "name": "company/company-elements",
  "description": "Elements for the company",
  "type": "shopware-platform-plugin",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "homepage": ""
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Company\\CompanyElements\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "plugin-icon": "src/Resources/config/plugin.png",
    "shopware-plugin-class": "Company\\CompanyElements\\CompanyElements",
    "label": {
      "de-DE": "Elemente für Firma",
      "en-GB": "Elements for Company"
    }
  }
}
```

My Class

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\CompanyElements;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin;

class CompanyElements extends Plugin
{
}
```

In my plugin I have this structure

[image]

My index.js

```
import template from './sw-cms-sidebar.html.twig';

Shopware.Component.override('sw-cms-sidebar', {
    template
});
```

My Template:

```
{% block sw_cms_sidebar_block_overview_category_options %}
    {% parent %}
    <option value="custom">Custom</option>
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately I don't see the category in the dropdown. And I don't know where is my mistake...

Edit: I also have a main.js with

```
import './extension/sw-cms/component/sw-cms-sidebar';


import './module/sw-cms/elements/eurobaustoff-catalog';
import './module/sw-cms/blocks/text-image/catalog';

import deDE from './module/sw-cms/snippet/de-DE.json';
import enGB from './module/sw-cms/snippet/en-GB.json';

Shopware.Locale.extend('de-DE', deDE);
Shopware.Locale.extend('en-GB', enGB);
```

Comment: Please check out your Console log. Always There is  useful information in there

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your `src/Resources/app/administration/src/main.js` which is automatically detected by the webpack compiler. You always need this entry file.

Within this `main.js` you have to include all your modules.
In your case:

```
import './extension/sw-cms/component/sw-cms-sidebar';
```

You can have a look at our [CMS Grid Blocks Plugin](https://github.com/Shape-and-Shift/shopware-cms-grid-blocks/blob/master/src/Resources/app/administration/src/main.js#L1) where we exactly did what you're trying to do.